# How to remove training dataset from a Matlab Generalized Linear Model object

Tags: matlab

I have a classification model in matlab2015a generated using

```
glm =  fitglm(Ttrain,...)
```

I want to keep glm and pass it around, but matlab also keeps the training data (Ttrain - a table) bound to the object. This can become prohibitive if you have many models + large training data sets (you can easily run out of memory). However doing something naive like setting:

```
glm.Variables= [];
```

gives

```
Error using classreg.regr.FitObject/subsasgn (line 753)
The Variables property for class GeneralizedLinearModel is read-only.
```

How do I discard the training data from the linear model, but still be able to use all the convenience and safety of calling `glm.predict(...)`? (I could of course rip out the regression coefficients and do the predict logic myself, but I prefer not to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this, I'm afraid.

For most other model types, such as `RegressionTree`, `ClassificationSVM` and so on, there is a companion model class such as `CompactRegressionTree`, `CompactClassificationSVM` and so on, that are the same but without retaining the training data (and slightly reduced diagnostic functionality because of that, but retaining the ability to predict).

I hadn't realized this until now, but it looks like the `LinearModel`, `NonLinearModel` and `GeneralizedLinearModel` classes don't have such an equivalent.

I'm afraid I can't think of an easy workaround for that. I would put in an enhancement request to MathWorks for it (log into your MathWorks account and go to the support section), as I can't think of a reason why it would be difficult, and it would make for a more consistent set of functionality.

---

Edit: Looks like MathWorks are gradually introducing this functionality. `CompactLinearModel` was introduced in R2016a, and `CompactGeneralizedLinearModel` was introduced in R2016b. As of R2017a, however, there's still no `CompactNonLinearModel`.

Comment: cool, thanks for your reply - I will indeed submit the request and if MW  agrees with you, I shall mark this as the correct answer - thanks again.

Comment: Indeed, MW agrees that this is impossible, plus they already have an enhancement request.