# What is the most efficient way to do a large number of regressions in MATLAB and store the result?

Tags: arrays, matlab, linear-regression, least-squares

I would like to make several hundreds of simple OLS regression estimations in MATLAB. Because it is hardly feasible to create a model object for each estimation I would instead like to store the parameter estimates and the associated standard errors in a numeric array or a structure, depending on what is more convenient. I have an `N` by `K` numerical array `Y` of values of the response variable and a corresponding numerical array `X` values of the predictor variable.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar: here's my code:

```
lModel = fitglm(X, Y(:, idx) ) 
Tcoefs = lModel.Coefficients;
```

then `Tcoefs` is just your table of coefficients + std. errors for the idx'd outcome... (I think, it has the errors) Also see this question: [How to remove training dataset from a Matlab Generalized Linear Model object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29143069/how-to-remove-training-dataset-from-a-matlab-generalized-linear-model-object/29146391#29146391)